# Checking a string to match a Char variable

Tags: c++, string

I have written a short program that takes a user input and then checks a string for a match to the users input but I need to add another function that checks make sure that the user input is in the string and if its not to return an error.

Here is my code for reference:

```
const string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,’ ";
int main()
{
    char letter; //Variable holding user entered letter 
    cout << "Please enter letter in the aplhabet:" << endl;
    cin >> letter;
    cout << "The Position of " << letter << " in the string is: " << ALPHABET.find(letter) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think I ought to add an if/else statement that first checks to see if the input is correct and if it is output the position in the string and if not return and error.

Comment: By definition, anything that the user enters will be a string.  What specific requirements do you wish to impose on the contents of the string?

Comment: Before printing out the index, check the return value you get from `ALPHABET.find` for the value `std::string::npos`.  This means the user's entry was not found in the string.

Comment: If you already have an idea about how to do it, why do you ask a question instead of directly trying it yourself? It would be faster.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Basically the user enters a single character in the Alphabet and then the function checks it against the string to find the single characters position in the string and the returns that position to the user. I now need it to give and error if the user trys to enter a character that is not included in the string "ALPHABET".

Comment: @Johnapples: So again, what is the actual problem? You have the user's character, you have the string to search for it in, and you have the result of `find()`, which tells you if the character was found or not.  If the returned index is `std::string::npos`, output an error message, otherwise output the index value. What is so hard about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to be fancy, you could write your own function. However,  `string::find()` is ok. All you need to check is whether or not the returned index is valid or not.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


const string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,’ ";
int main()
{
    char letter; //Variable holding user entered letter 
    string::size_type index; //Index where char is found in string
    cout << "Please enter letter in the aplhabet:" << endl;
    cin >> letter;

    index =  ALPHABET.find(letter);

    if (index == string::npos)
        cout << "Error, letter not found" << endl;
    else
        cout << "The Position of " << letter << " in the string is: " << index << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string::find()` returns `std::string::npos` (-1) if the character is not found.  You need to look for that value specifically, not check for `index > length()` (which is completely wrong), eg: `std::string::size_type index; ... if (index == std::string::npos) ...`

Comment: std::string::npos is simply the greatest possible value for an element of size_t. My solution does essentially the same time. Thanks for being pretentious though.

Comment: "*the greatest possible value*" - you are assuming `std::string::size_type` is always unsigned, which is not always true. By *default*, it is `std::size_t`, which is indeed unsigned.  But the actual type of `std::string::size_type` depends on the `allocator` used. Best not to make any assumptions about the type or the value. `std::string::npos` specifically represents "no valid position in the string", so that is what you should be checking for. Otherwise there is no point in `npos` existing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

An if/else statement sounds good. And if that doesn't work, there are other multiple ways that it could.